# AppEngine/Go: urlfetch vs http.Get, etc

Tags: google-app-engine, go, urlfetch

Is it necessary to use `urlfetch` under AppEngine? I'd like to write a generic client to use with one of my services, but, if `urlfetch` is required from AppEngine, how can I write a generic client for use both from outside AppEngine (for the public) and inside AppEngine (for my other services) without having to write two different versions or passing some kind of factory that produces the right implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application should pass an http.Client to your generic client. It can either be a parameter to the function or passed through a [context](https://godoc.org/context#Context) as done in the [oauth2 package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2#HTTPClient).

If the application does not provide a http.Client through one of these mechanisms (nil arg or no value in context), then use the [default client](https://godoc.org/net/http#DefaultClient).

Comment: I didn't get that they're the same client type while configured differently.